# Choosing a folder with JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, filesystems, jfilechooser

I want the user to choose where should a certain file be produced in which folder using `aJFileChooser`. However, I do not want the user to choose a file, but a folder only.

How would i go on about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [`JFileChooser#setFileSelectionMode(int mode)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setFileSelectionMode%28int%29)

> Sets the JFileChooser to allow the user to just select files, just
>   select directories, or select both files and directories. The default
>   is JFilesChooser.FILES_ONLY. 
>  Parameters: 
> mode - the type
>   of files to be displayed: 
>  - JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY 
>  -
>   JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY 
>  -
>   JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES

Answer (score 3):

You would use [setFileSelectionMode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setFileSelectionMode%28int%29):

> Sets the JFileChooser to allow the user to just select files, just select directories, or select both files and directories. The default is JFilesChooser.FILES_ONLY.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that as follows:

```
fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
```